# Connect to External Monitor - Acer S231HL - No Signal

Tags: laptop, hdmi

I've been looking for an answer every and can't seem to find a solution.

**Backstory**

I recently bought a new laptop with an HDMI port which I want to take advantage of.  I have an 23" external monitor (Acer S231HL) which has a VGA, DVI, and HDMI input.  Previously, I used the VGA or DVI to connect a laptop to the monitor.

**Problem**

When I connect this new laptop, I get a "No Signal" message on the monitor.  The laptop does not detect it.

**What I have tired**

I connected the laptop with HDMI to my TV and everything worked flawlessly so I can only assume this is an issue with the monitor.

Weird Issue:  When everythings plugged in, the laptop does not detect any monitor.  When I unplug the POWER of the external monitor (HDMI still intact), the laptop then detects the correct monitor.  When I plug the power back in, it stops detecting it.

I tried a hard reset on the monitor.  Restarting the laptop.